# Explanatory variables may bias predictions

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, inference, bias, predictor

I' m asking this question out of sheer curiosity, my teacher was not able to explain it.

If I'm using logistic regression with categorical variables they are coded like {1,2,3}. I guess it wouldn't change my results if I used {4,5,6}. But what if linearity of coding wasn't kept? (say {4,10,99})? What I deal with is just the way of coding factor variables but is it possible that the statistical inference could be "distorted" this way? Or, worst case scenario, would I be able to draw nonsense conclusions from categorical data just because they are coded in some way?

Answer (score 11):

The point is that you don't *code* levels of categorical variables as 1,2,3 even if you *call* them that. You *code* them using dummy variables, e.g. 
$$\begin{array}{l c c}
&x_1&x_2\\
\text{level 1} &0 & 0\\
\text{level 2} &1 & 0\\
\text{level 3} &0 & 1\\
\end{array}$$
so that when the linear predictor is given by
$$\eta = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_1 +\beta_2 x_2$$
$\beta_0$ is the log odds for level 1, $\beta_1$ is the log odds ratio between level 2 & level 1, & $\beta_2$ is the log odds ratio between level 3 & level 1. Different coding schemes can be used (see [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm)), changing the interpretation of the coefficients but not materially changing the model (i.e. the same predictor values give the same predicted response).

Answer (score 5):

If your software treats a *factor* variable with factor levels 1, 2, 3 as *numeric*, your model and your predictions will be garbage, simply because the difference (on the link scale) between groups 1 and 3 will be fitted to be double the difference between groups 1 and 2, which will usually not make sense.

So: tell your software that 1, 2, 3 are factors. Better still, use A, B, C. No honest software will misunderstand A, B, C as numeric.