# Can text features be represented by / used as numeric?

Tags: classification, categorical-data

I have a set of about 20000 objects, with 35 features. Some of the features are numeric, and some of the features are like 'gthad12ja'. (There are a finite number of this strings, for example feature_14 can be 'gthad12ja', 'a11qwzxcja', 'plzxq11qqz'.) Can I encode 'gthad12ja' as 0, 'a11qwzxcja' as 1, 'plzxq11qqz' as 2, and use this feature as numeric?

What else can I do with them?

Comment: In **R**, you would encode such features as *factors*.  Why language are you using?

Comment: It's worth noting that  factor coding in R is just a data type that is typically subsequently expanded to *dummy coding*.

Comment: I use python-language

Comment: What information relevant to the classification you're going to perform do the different strings contain? Can 'gthad12ja' be seen as twice 'a11qwzxcja', or as greater than it? If there's nothing more than possession of different attributes to consider, treat them as categorical variables & use a dummy coding system - see: eg [Contrast Coding Systems for categorical variables](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm) & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/100173/17230).

Comment: Dummy coding is not specific to any software environment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Advice: 
try it, build a model from the change and see what effect it has. 
These is data-specific question that must be tested.

Also usefull links:
http://machinelearningmastery.com/discover-feature-engineering-how-to-engineer-features-and-how-to-get-good-at-it/

Comment: (-1) There's no reason to suppose 'gthad12ja' &c. even represent *ordered* categories.

Comment: These is data-specific question that must be tested.

Comment: If there are, say, 20 string features, each with 3 levels, then there are 120 different representations of this form (each as 1, 2, or 3), none with any particular justification. Do you test all of them? From your link:-"Feature importance and selection can inform you about the objective utility of features, but those features have to come from somewhere. You need to manually create them. This requires spending a lot of time [...] thinking about the underlying form of the problem, structures in the data and how best to expose them to predictive modeling algorithms".